# How to prevent routing failures in BizTalk

Tags: biztalk

I have a BizTalk app which consumes a generic envelope message which gets devolved into four possible message types once inside BizTalk.

For three of these message types subscribers exist, the forth type generates a routing failure because there are no subscribers.

My question is can anyone think of a nice way to handle this? We can't really prevent these messages from coming in.

I don't just want to set up a send port to subscribe to these things because that will involve support overhead (clearing out the messages from a folder etc).

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no nice way to handle this. Maybe [configure error recive port](http://lwang00.wordpress.com/2007/12/03/configure-biztalk-failed-message-routing/) to make it more clear. But message needs to be processed, otherwise "Subscription not found" exception happens. In a system I'm currently working with this situation is dealt with a '*No Op*' orchestration, with consists of only one receieve shape, so a message "dies" within it.

P.S. [one more solution](http://winterdom.com/2005/03/biztalk2004nullsendadaptersample).

Comment: Thanks Petr - I will try your empty orch solution.

Comment: +1 - we also use the Null Adapter for subscriptions under construction